# Passing arguments from REST API application properties to registered ApplicationEventListener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jersey

In one of my use case I want to pass multiple parameters from application resource properties of Spring boot Rest API and this parameters should be listen by registered ApplicationEventListener or by ApplicationEvent in Jersey. Can some body please suggest me how can I achieve this. Below is my code base

```
package com.learning;
import org.springframework.boot.context.ApplicationPidFileWriter;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
public class ABCApplication {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
    SpringApplication.run(ABCApplication.class, args);
    context.addApplicationListener(new ApplicationPidFileWriter());
    context.addApplicationListener(new TestingListener());
}
}
```

Here is my Listener which should be triggered and recieve these parameters from Rest API.

```
  import org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.ApplicationEvent;
  import org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.ApplicationEventListener;

  public class TestingListener implements ApplicationEventListener {

  @Override
  public void onEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {

    if (event.getType() == 
   ApplicationEvent.Type.INITIALIZATION_APP_FINISHED) {
        final ResourceModel resourceModel = event.getResourceModel();
        final ResourceLogDetails logDetails = new 
       ResourceLogDetails();
        resourceModel.getResources().stream().forEach((resource) -> {    
       logDetails.addEndpointLogLines(getLinesFromResource(resource));
        });
        logDetails.log();
    }
}
```

Attaching my resource

```
   @Api
   @Path("/resource")
   public static class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/get/path")
    public String getMethod() {
        return "get";
    }

    @POST
    public void post(String entity) {
    }

}
```

So the output I am expecting is

```
  GET  resource/get/path
  POST resource
```

But this is my business logic and I want to get some more values here which should come from application resources properties file.

Comment: have you already tried something? where is your REST controller?

Comment: Hi @rick, I dont know the way to pass these arguments thats what my question is. I am looking for suggestions. I have attached my Resource as well which is serving the purpose of Rest Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ok since for me is not clear what and how you need to manage vents I give you a standard example:

To Publish an event in spring boot you can create a service that manage the pubblication:

```
@Component
public class CustomSpringEventPublisherService {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    public void publishCustomEvent(final String message) {
        System.out.println("Publishing custom event. ");
        CustomSpringEvent customSpringEvent = new CustomSpringEvent(this, message);
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(customSpringEvent);
    }
}
```

CustomSpingEvent is a POJO containing your payload and the source:

```
public class CustomSpringEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private String message;

    public CustomSpringEvent(Object source, String message) {
        super(source);
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Then you can implement a listener like this:

```
@Component
public class AnnotationDrivenContextStartedListener {

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextStart(CustomSpringEvent event) {
        System.out.println("A custom event and his payload ->"+event.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now in your case you can implement the listener as shown and in the controller you can put the publisher service:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class YourController {

```
 private final CustomSpringEventPublisherService customSpringEventPublisherService;

public YourController(CustomSpringEventPublisherService customSpringEventPublisherService) {
    this.customSpringEventPublisherService = customSpringEventPublisherService;
}


@GetMapping(value = "/resource")
public ResponseEntity<PublicationDto> getResource() {
    // Create CustomSpringEvent
    CustomSpringEvent customSpringEvent = new CustomSpringEvent(...)

    this.customSpringEventPublisherService.publishCustomEvent(customSpringEvent);
}
```

}

This is really conceptual work and not tested.

Hope it helps you understand how it works

Comment: Hello Rick, Thanks for your effort . Although this is not what I am looking for.The event will be managed by server context. If you see there is condition ApplicationEvent.Type.INITIALIZATION_APP_FINISHED, so as soon as server will start this will invoke onEvent and it will execute one time.                                                           Well I am able to see the output as well but I dont know how can I pass some label values from application properties of Rest API to this listener. I hope this time it is more clear.

Comment: Application properties can be injected in any spring component that's not the problem. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties. I'm sorry I cannot help you more but I really cannot anduerstand what you are trying to do